# How to set default directory of QFileDialog on Windows WinRT

Tags: qt, windows-runtime, qfiledialog

I want to open a QFileDialog with a specific default directory to select a file. Argument "url" of *QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl* seems to be made for that, but I can't make it work. Here is what I've done :

```
QUrl url("file:///D:/");
QUrl path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl(0, "Open File", url, tr("Database (*.db)"));
```

It does not work, default directory is not set.

I'm running Windows 10 and I compile with msvc2015 for WinRT platform.

Edit : Seems to be a bug, I filled a ticket : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57464

Comment: Have you traced into the `getOpenFileUrl` to see what it does with the `url`? If not, then make a debug build of Qt so that you can debug into it. It'll make you way more productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think working directly with path string is more conventional when it comes to local files because QUrl is designed for dealing with all sorts of URLs. So I suggest using getOpenFileName instead.

```
QString defaultPath ="D:/";
QString ret = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, "Open File", defaultPath, tr("Database (*.db)"));
```

But if you need to use QUrl somehow, you can use it like this.

```
QUrl url= QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:/");
QUrl path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl(0, "Open File", url, tr("Database (*.db)"));
```

Comment: Sadly, both of the propositions don't work. Did you manage to get this to work on Windows 10 / WinRT / Qt 5.7 ?

Comment: Yes, i tried these. My OS and qt versions are same as yours. Note that I do not use file:/// prefix

Comment: Yes I saw that the prefix was remove. Sorry to insist, but are you sure you compile for WinRT ? Your code works for me with Desktop Qt 5.7 for Windows 10 but not for WinRT 5.7.

Comment: By OS i meant win10 only. I tried it only at desktop. It was supposed to work on all win 10 devices :(.  if your device is a phone, or smth like that, your app needs permissions to be set to reach certain directories, you probably did this if you can open by not using default file, I guess.

Comment: The QFileDialog does not need any permissions as it explicitely asks the user to access a file. Thank for your testings, it seems to be a bug in WinRT port. I added an issue and accept your answer as it will be working once the bug fixed.

Comment: @Oswin I think you should answer your question and tell that this is about a bug, and choose that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, probably due to a bug int Qt WinRT port.

See : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57464

Once the bug fixed, t.m.'s answer should work